# Bootstrap form - scroll does not appear when screen is resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, resize

I'm working on a project with a Bootstrap form. Very simply, I would like the form to have a scroll bar when the window is resized. I tried adding the overflow-auto class to my div, but that doesn't work for it. So when I resize my window, no scroll appears. Here's my code.

```css
.form-container {
 border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 15px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.register-container { max-width: 500px; }

.title-header {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-auto container form-container register-container">
    <h1 class="title-header">REGISTER</h1>
    <form id="register" method="post" action="register">
        <?php writeMessageBoxIfMessage($message); ?>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">FIRST NAME</label> <br>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">LAST NAME</label> <br>
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">EMAIL</label> <br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="255" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">PASSWORD</label> <br>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label> <br>
                <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                Already have an account? <br> Click <a href="login">here</span></a> to login.
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="register" type="submit" name="submit"
                    value="REGISTER" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Can anyone provide some suggestions so I can get this to scroll?

Comment: It is because of the fixed position of the container. Does this have to be vertically centered?

Answer (score 1):

Can’t replicate this at the moment but try using
position: absolute;

and give a container 
position: relative;

Rather than using the ‘fixed’ position.

Let me know if this doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want internal scroll if the form is more in height.

Use the following CSS,

Try it.

```
#register {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Please add media

```
@media (max-height: 420px) {
  #register {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

for better solution and check your device height should be (max-height: yourDeviceHeight) in media

```css
.form-container {
 border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 15px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.register-container { max-width: 500px; }

.title-header {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
}


@media (max-height: 420px) {
  #register {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-auto container form-container register-container">
    <h1 class="title-header">REGISTER</h1>
    <form id="register" method="post" action="register">
        <?php writeMessageBoxIfMessage($message); ?>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">FIRST NAME</label> <br>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">LAST NAME</label> <br>
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">EMAIL</label> <br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="255" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">PASSWORD</label> <br>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label> <br>
                <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" maxlength="80" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                Already have an account? <br> Click <a href="login">here</span></a> to login.
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="register" type="submit" name="submit"
                    value="REGISTER" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```